# java.lang.Error: Error Copying Database in SQLite Database from assets folder

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have designed the database in SQLlite Browser. And now I got this error.
the database cannot copy from assets folder.

it shows me this error

```
2021-01-13 13:35:26.126 9933-9933/com.example.wallpaperapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.wallpaperapp, PID: 9933
    java.lang.Error: Error Copying Database
        at com.example.wallpaperapp.utils.SqliteHelperClass.onCreateDatabase(SqliteHelperClass.java:50)
        at com.example.wallpaperapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
```

SQLiteHelper Class

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class SqliteHelperClass extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    Context context;
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    public static final String dbname = "wallpaperApp.db";
    public String dbPath = "";

    public SqliteHelperClass(Context context) {
        super(context, dbname, null, 1);
        this.context = context;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 15) {

            this.dbPath = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";

        } else {
            this.dbPath = Environment.getDataDirectory() + "/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + "database/";
        }

    }

    //Create the Database
    public void onCreateDatabase() throws IOException {
        boolean dbExist = checkDatabase();

        if (dbExist) {

        } else {
            try {
                this.getReadableDatabase();
                copyDatabase();

            } catch (Exception e) {

                throw new Error("Error Copying Database");
            }
        }

    }

    //check Database

    private boolean checkDatabase() {

        SQLiteDatabase checkDb = null;
        try {
            String mypath = dbPath + dbname;
            checkDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mypath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }

        if (checkDb != null) {
            checkDb.close();
        }

        return checkDb != null? true : false;

    }

    private void copyDatabase() throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open(dbname);

        String outFilename = dbPath = dbname;
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFilename);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        inputStream.close();

    }

    public void openDatabase() throws Exception {
        String mypath = dbPath + dbname;
        db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mypath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (db != null) {
            db.close();
        }
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        if (oldVersion > newVersion) {
            try {
                copyDatabase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
    public Cursor readData(String query){

        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);
        return cursor;
    }

    public void updateDataForFavorite(String id, String isFav)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("isFav",isFav);
        database.update("wallpapers",contentValues,"id=?",new String[]{id});

    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.wallpaperapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.wallpaperapp.adapters.GridViewAdapter;
import com.example.wallpaperapp.models.ImagesConstant;
import com.example.wallpaperapp.utils.SqliteHelperClass;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    GridView gridView;
    GridViewAdapter gridViewAdapter;
    List<ImagesConstant> imagesConstantList;

    SqliteHelperClass sqLiteHelperClass;
    Cursor cursor = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        imagesConstantList  = new ArrayList<>();

        sqLiteHelperClass = new SqliteHelperClass(MainActivity.this);

        try {
            sqLiteHelperClass.onCreateDatabase();
            sqLiteHelperClass.openDatabase();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        addData();
    }

    private void addData() {
        cursor = sqLiteHelperClass.readData("SELECT id, images, isFav from wallpapers;");
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){

            do {

                int id = cursor.getInt(0);
                String image = cursor.getString(1);
                int isFav = cursor.getInt(2);

                ImagesConstant imagesConstant = new ImagesConstant(id,image,isFav);

                imagesConstantList.add(imagesConstant);

            }while (cursor.moveToNext());

            showGrid();

        }else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    void showGrid(){

        gridViewAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(MainActivity.this,imagesConstantList);
        gridView.setAdapter(gridViewAdapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which statement causes the error?

Comment: `"Error Copying Database"` That is your own message. That does not bring your further. And you are nor even printing the stacktrace. And you are not logging e.getMessage() nor use it when you throw. Please do and tell us the value of e.getMessage().

Comment: Please tell the value of outFilename.

Comment: You know you have to deinstall your app after every failed try?